# What type of gloves should be used while diluting sulfuric and hydrochloric acids?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, safety, materials, gloves

What type of gloves should we use on hands while diluting sulfuric and hydrochloric acid?

Can we use these gloves in chemistry lab to handle other acids?

Comment: And why do you think normal ones won't do?

Comment: @Mithoron define *normal* -- for some that would still mean latex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [numerous](https://ehs.berkeley.edu/workplace-safety/glove-selection-guide#comparison) [sources](https://www.ishn.com/articles/90718-what-is-the-best-glove) [online](http://amo-csd.lbl.gov/downloads/Chemical%20Resistance%20of%20Gloves.pdf) [comparing](https://www.ansellpro.com/download/Ansell_7thEditionChemicalResistanceGuide.pdf) polymer materials resistivity in hazardous environments, but most of them agree that in your case ordinary *nitrile gloves* would protect in case of incidental contact, and *butyl rubber/neoprene/PVC gloves* are more suitable if a prolonged exposure is expected.

Nitrile gloves are disposable and cheap, and always should be changed when contaminated with chemicals as they only offer basic protection.